# The interplay of this two verbs

Tags: grammar, て-form

The following sentence:
この庭にある大きい石と池は、富士山と海を**イメージして**造られました。

This イメージ**して** followed by 造られました irritates me. I know of several specific patterns where て form is directly succeeded by another verb like
星が見えてきた
but I don't know of any such case with 造る. I've little idea how to understand this phrase.

Comment: If what troubles you is the mixture of active voice and passive voice, this one is related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15140/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no grammatical problem here.  I would translate this as

> This garden's large rock and the lake were made to give the impression of Mt Fuji and the sea.

Even in English there is a mixture of passive and active, but there's nothing awkward or ungrammatical about this.

I wouldn't lump this in with constructions like 星が見えてきた。 The てくる form there is a fixed grammatical form.  There are other uses of the て-form of verbs which can express reason or purpose.  For example,

> 一所懸命{いっしょうけんめい}勉強{べんきょう}して試験{しけん}を合格{ごうかく}した。
>
> Having studied hard, I passed the exam.

Comment: Hm, I can see what you mean. But this combination of active て form and passive, resulting in a construction expressing what we would express through a consecutive clause of result, is indeed new to me. 

Why must my textbook always come up with stuff it hasn't taught me about before -.- Constructions like this would only be possible with nominalization, for example: ...ことに造られた. 
I don't know if this would be grammatical, but it's the only way I could think up with the grammar Ive learnt so far.

Comment: @Narktor I understand the frustration with textbooks.  I've been there many times myself.

Comment: I don't see how you could use the construction ...ことに造られた in this context.  To my ear it sounds strange, but then I don't have a native speaker's ear.  If you were to try to rephrase it, I might try イメージするために, though even that sounds a bit strange.  It'd be nice if a native speaker could chime in on this point.

Comment: Textbooks can rarely cover everything, especially not in the order the real world throws them at you. I agree with A. Ellet about ことに造られた not working out in that context. If I were to try to rephrase the bit that bothers you, I,d probably flip the sentence around: 富士山と海をイメージをイメージに、この庭にある…